# Using variable in Bash with the command nl (number lines of files) in a script

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to create a script that will allow me to write a list of songs to a text file with the following format:

```
#01 - Artist - Title
#02 - Artist - Title
#03 - Artist - Title
#04 - Artist - Title
etc.
```

I export the artist and title from Spotify and need to manually adjust some of the format in some cases. I'll be doing that by hand for now but might attempt to automate that later on. For now I want to put the artist - title in the TRACKS variable and want to run the script to appened it with the `#NUMBER - Artist - Title`. I'm currently just using `echo "${NL}"` to test if my output comes out correctly before I write it to a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TRACKS=$(cat <<-END
Artist - Title
Artist - Title
Artist - Title
Artist - Title
END
)

$NL=$(echo "${TRACKS}" | nl -nrz -w2 -s" - " -) 

echo "${NL}"
```

The problem I'm having is that no matter how I use the command nl either as stated below or simply as `$NL=nl inputfile.txt` the script returns a `"command not found"`. I have no clue why I can't use it in a variable. I've tried specifying the exact path to the binary with no luck. The only way it works is if use it as `nl inputfile.txt` without specifying it as a variable. Essentially the same as running it from the command line directly.

Comment: Set the variable as `NL=...`, no `$`.

Comment: Consider whether you actually need to use `TRACKS` as you are now. You could make it an array (one track per element), and more to the point here, `nl` can read directly from a here document like `cat` does here.

Comment: I'm just starting out with bash scripting and I'm not entirely sure how to realise what I want to do using an array and loops. I'm sure there are other ways to realise what I want to do but I came across `nl` and `sed` which in two commands lets me realise the output I want. I'm aware `nl` accepts input from documents and I might separate it to take the input from a txt file with the manually cleaned up information from Spotify for now. Perhaps in the future I'll be able to script the manual cleanup part as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a dollar sign when performing an assignment:

Change this:

```
$NL=$(echo "${TRACKS}" | nl -nrz -w2 -s" - " -)
```

To This:

```
NL=$(echo "${TRACKS}" | nl -nrz -w2 -s" - " -)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That did it. I'm just starting out with scripting and trying to piece some stuff together. Can't believe I made this rather silly mistake.